# How can I create an ion-reorder-group from a firestore collection

Tags: ionic-framework, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create an ion-reorder-group from a firestore collection. more precisely from an observable object since the list to be reordered can be updated in real time.

I got some code from @Mirinda Corwin here ([Ionic / Firebase - error splice is not a function (reorderArray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400606/ionic-firebase-error-splice-is-not-a-function-reorderarray)).

This is my code adapted from Mirinda's answer:

```
import { Observable, ObjectUnsubscribedError } from "rxjs";
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

public membersListRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
public membersList$: Observable < any []>;
public membersList = {} as any;
public membersArray: any[];

...

this.membersArray = [];
this.membersListRef = this.firestore.collection(`/userProfile/${this.groupNumber}/membersList`);
this.membersList$ = this.membersListRef.valueChanges();

...

this.membersList$.take(1).subscribe((members) => {
  members.forEach(mdoc=>{
    console.log("id: , name:" + mdoc.id, mdoc.name);
       return  this.membersArray.push({id: mdoc.id, name:mdoc.name })
     })
   });
```

but I get the following error: "take is not a property of observable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of RxJS changed the method of how to apply operators to the stream, you should use "pipe" method:

```
this.membersList$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...);
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html